# How to set bar chart to use just the values passed into the bar function?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This code to display a simple bar chart:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

x = [1]
height = [8]
width = 1.0

plt.bar(x, height, width, color='b' )

plt.savefig('SimpleBar.png')
plt.show()
```

produces:

[image]

How to display a single value for the bar? In this case, display 1 instead of `0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

x = [1]
height = [8]
width = 1.0

plt.bar(x, height, width, color='b')
plt.xticks([1])                                     # add this line
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

There is the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) for you to read more.